# How to use Scrapy Shell in WinPython and by using IPython?

Tags: windows, shell, scrapy, ipython, scrapy-shell

I would like to learn scrapy and I can use scrapy shell in the regular Windows shell.

As soon as I type scrapy shell 'url' in IPython i get the subsequent message:

```
scrapy shell http://quotes.toscrape.com/
  File "<ipython-input-1-7ffa7d14a3eb>", line 1
    scrapy shell http://quotes.toscrape.com/
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It makes sense to me, since nothing in my system, especially IPython, doesn't know about scrapy yet.

But could you pls help me to fix that? The scrapy documentation itself doesn't offer a concrete solution. Is the problem maybe based on the Winpython distribution? I tried several ideas, but didn't find a solution :/

Comment: Add the quotes: `scrapy shell "http://quotes.toscrape.com/"`

Comment: Unfortunately, it also doesn't work.  Same error.